# SwifUI: expand specific row in list with children key-path

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui, children

I made a List with children key path like this:

```
        List(My_data, children: \.children) {row in
                Text(row.content)
        }
```

It is created an expandable rows (in close state).. Is there away to expand specific row progromaticlly ?

Comment: It all depends on your struct : does MyData.children’s is an array of row ?

Comment: Yes it is an array of rows .. type [MyData]